# Foreground service that only registers a receiver is 26MB, how do I make it smaller or find out where the size comes from?

Tags: java, android

I have a predefined pattern I need to vibrate ocassionally at will when phone is in my pocket, I came upon the conclusion that the best way to do this was pressing power button twice in rapid succession.

I'm checking if the power button is pressed by using screen off and screen on intents and since they can't be registered in the manifest I start a service and register the broadcast receiver there. I tried using a background service but it kept getting killed at the 1 minute mark and unregistering the receiver so I used a foreground service instead. (I think it gets killed because it's quite heavy and not doing anything)

```
//Service.java

// Register the receiver that's in it's own file Receiver.java

public void onCreate() {
    nmang = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this,getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + " Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("service.onCreate", "Service started");
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    this.receiver = new Receiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    startForeground(1, makeNotif("Running", R.drawable.ic_clock)); // returns a notification with the text "running"

}

// Receiver calls the service when two fast consecutive power button presses occur

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("service.onStart()", "Service called with "+ intent.getAction());
    if(intent.hasCategory("VIBRATE_CATEGORY")){
        Pattern.vibrate(this); //Pattern class in Pattern.java has the pattern stored and a static vibrate method.
                              //Could move to this file as functions but figured it's cleaner this way.
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + " Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    nmang.notify(1, makeNotif("SERVICE STOPPED", R.drawable.ic_stopped));
    Log.d("service.onDestroy()", "Service stopped");
    if (receiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);

}
```

If all I have is a service that registers a receiver and calls a static method when the receiver tells it to why is it taking up so many resources? How do I figure out what's taking up that much space?

I notice under running services it's listed as "1 process and 1 service" not sure if this has any relevance.

Any help with this or a better way of doing what I want would be hugely appreciated. There's also a big chance I'm misunderstanding all of this as this is my first android app.

PS: I didn't include Receiver.java code because I've tried not using it and not registering a receiver at all and the service is still the same size. Tell me if I should include.

Comment: Is that storage space or used memory? Because they're very different.

Comment: the app is 1.95 MB (also seems high considering it only has a button to stop the service), under  developer options > running services > my app > under processes it's listed as 26 MB

Comment: In case you were not aware and want to distribute this to many people: on Galaxy S phones pressing the power button quickly twice is used to open up the camera so you can quickly take a picture.

Comment: @SarelBotha I'm aware but that doesn't affect me, thanks (I don't think there's any way to trigger if phone is in pocket other than power button)

Comment: Both of those seem normal. You're using support libraries, which are compiled into your app, and there's also the general overhead of an APK file. 26MB for a Service is very low, and probably isn't much more than the overhead needed for the process.

Comment: Another option might be via bluetooth or an NFC button stuck on the phone.

Comment: Read up on shared memory too. Some of this memory might be for shared libraries already being used by other apps, so your app is not really adding this much more RAM usage to the phone: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35138/9448

Comment: Can you do a memory dump of the process and then inspect the dump? You can do this with a java process on a computer. I am not familiar enough with Android development.

Comment: Most other app's services in my phone are lower and run for hours without getting killed (and aren't foreground), but mine gets killed at the 1 minute mark unless I start as foreground. I figure the system kills it because it needs more memory and my app is one of the highest consuming.

Comment: I'll look up how to do a memory dump, thanks

Comment: not sure if this is what you meant https://i.imgur.com/w85J1K6.png or what exactly to take out of this. I guess it is normal after all? I just see all these other services with way less memory and wonder how they do it.